# How to show that a set of vectors is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the set of vectors of the form $[ a, b, a+2b ]$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

How to show this? The definition of a subspace $S$ requires showing that if $u,v \in S$ and $c \in \mathbb R$, then $S$ contains:

1. zero vector
2. $u+v$
3. $cu$

Can anyone help me with this problem and explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the indicated set is the image of $\mathbb R^2$ under the mapping induced by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: how did you know the values of the variables can you explain it to me?

Comment: Calculate the matrix product $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide, with some areas for you to fill in.  Note that this is not a complete solution.

Let's call "Property X" the property a vector $(x,y,z)$ can have, where $z=x+2y$.  Vectors having this property are of the form $[a,b,a+2b]$, and vice versa.  In other words, Property X characterizes the property of being in the desired set of vectors.

Step 1: Prove that $(0,0,0)$ has Property X.

Step 2.  Suppose that $u=(x,y,z)$ and $v=(x',y',z')$ both have Property X.  Using this, prove that $u+v=(x+x',y+y',z+z')$ also has Property X.

Step 3.  Suppose that $u=(x,y,z)$ has Property X, and that $c$ is an arbitrary real number.  Using this, prove that $cu=(cx,cy,cz)$ also has Property X.

Answer (score 1):

You have the definintion of a set of ordered triples.
i.e $(1,2,5)$ is a member of that set.

You need to prove that this set is a vector space.

If it is a vector space it must satisfy the axioms that define a vector space.

Among those axioms is closure under addition, closure under scalar multiplication, and the existence of a zero vector.

Lets tackle scalar multiplication first.  Choose a generic triple in your set.  Multiply all the entries in this tripple by some constant.

$k(a,b,a+2b) = (ka, 2b, ka + k2b)$

Is this also in your set?

Addition:

Choose two triples in your set and add them together.

$(a,b,a+2b)+ (x,y,x+2y) = (a+x, b+y, a+2b + x + 2y)$ is the resultant in your set?

zero.... is there a triple your set such that $\mathbf 0 + (a,b,a+2b) = (a,b,a+2b)$